# How to query data based on partition key and sort keys in dynamodb leaving few items in between

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDb table called Track with partition key 'id' (String) and sort key 'timestamp' (Number) in milliseconds. The data is inserted every 5 seconds.

Now I want to fetch data such that the result will have one item from each hour instead of all.

How to query the database?

I am using python and boto3 library.

My table looks like this:

```
table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Track',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'gpsid',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'timestamp',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  # Sort key
        }

    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'gpsid',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'timestamp',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        }

    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)
```

And the data looks like this:

[image: Copied from aws db]

Comment: Do you want to randomly select that one item from each hour ?

Comment: How do you store the timestamp data in DynamoDB? Can you show the sample timestamp data?

Comment: Yes one timestamp per hour and I have added the desc of the table in the question.